# Button drawableBottom Nexus 7 and Galaxy Tab 2

Tags: android, android-drawable

I am adapting an application written for a Galaxy Tab 2 (10".1) screen size to a Nexus 7 (7").
Following the suggestions here in stackoverflow I created different image sizes for all densities `(l|m|h|xh)dpi` and also a specific `layout-sw600dp` folder which contains my layouts modified for the 7 inches screen.

[EDIT]

And I added 
`<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"
     android:largeScreens="true"
     android:normalScreens="true"
     android:resizeable="true"
     android:smallScreens="true" />`

to my `Androidmanifest` file.

[/EDIT]

Notwithstanding all these modifications I am still struggling having the `drawableBottom` (and Top, Left, Right) of my `Buttons` correctly scaling between the two devices.

The physical size of the rendered images is the same. So the Nexus is making the icons as large as the Galaxy (or viceversa).

From what I understood the two devices, although being of different physical size, they share the same density of pixels (xhdpi), that makes the Nexus picking up from the xhdpi folder.
Am I missing something important?

How should I adapt my drawableBottoms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.

Probably this is not "THE" solution as it is meant to be. But it worked for me straight away and with a *minimum* effort considered the size of the application I had to adapt.

This following solution basically works quite nicely but (probably) only for this specific case since the Galaxy Tab 2 and the Nexus 7 share the same resolution.

How I fixed it with almost no work:

1. Do not create the smaller resolution images (you don't really need it), unless you are going to install (or have installed) your app in many other devices.
2. Create two values- folders. One for the Galaxy Tab 2 ( = xlarge), the other one for the Nexus 7 ( = large). The modifier is the size of the screen.
3. Inside each of the folders place a `dimen.xml` file which you will fill respectively like.

For the Galaxy Tab 2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
[...]
<dimen name="s25sp">25sp</dimen>
<dimen name="s30sp">30sp</dimen>
<dimen name="s35sp">35sp</dimen>
[...]
<dimen name="s25dp">25dp</dimen>
<dimen name="s30dp">30dp</dimen>
<dimen name="s35dp">35dp</dimen>
[...]
</resources>
```

For the Nexus 7:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
[...]
<dimen name="s25sp">17sp</dimen>
<dimen name="s30sp">21sp</dimen>
<dimen name="s35sp">24sp</dimen>
[...]
<dimen name="s25dp">17dp</dimen>
<dimen name="s30dp">21dp</dimen>
<dimen name="s35dp">24dp</dimen>
[...]
</resources>
```

Each value for the Nexus 7 is obtained like: Galaxy_value/10.1*7

1. After that you have to use the `@dimen/s[0-9]*dp` whenever you want to use that specific dimension.

PS:
If you have a big application with many layouts already formatted you could use this `PERL` script to convert every [0-9]*dp and [0-9]*sp into `@dimen/s[0-9]*dp`  `@dimen/s[0-9]*sp` automatically.
Here it is:

```
   #!/usr/bin/perl

   $filename = $ARGV[0];
   open (FILE, $filename);

   while (<FILE>) {
      chomp;

      if ( $_ =~ /\"[0-9]*(di?p|sp)\"/) {

         my $pre = $`;
         my $mat = $&;
         my $pos = $';

         $mat =~ s/["]+//g;

         print "$pre\"\@dimen/s$mat\"$pos\n";
      }  elsif ( ($_ !~ /\"[0-9]*dp\"/) && ($_ !~ /\"[0-9]*sp\"/) ) {      
         print "$_\n";
      }
   }

   close (FILE);
   exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure the app is designed for high density displays? Try adding this to your manifest after permissions:

```
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"
                  android:normalScreens="true"
                  android:smallScreens="true"
                  android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

Comment: Yes - this is what I've added:

`<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"
   android:largeScreens="true"
   android:normalScreens="true"
   android:resizeable="true"
   android:smallScreens="true" />`

Comment: Ok, sorry, that's all I've got.